# How to programmatically disable scrollbar inertia for my Qt application on a Mac?

Tags: macos, qt

In a Qt project, how would I go about disabling the OS X scrollbar inertia for my application? This is so that I can provide custom control over inertia etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does it:

`project.pro`

```
QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET = project
TEMPLATE = app
macx {
    LIBS += -framework Foundation
    OBJECTIVE_SOURCES += helper.m
}
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

`helper.m`

```
#include <Foundation/NSUserDefaults.h>
#include <Foundation/NSDictionary.h>
#include <Foundation/NSString.h>

void disableMomentumScroll(void)
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"NO" forKey:@"AppleMomentumScrollSupported"];
    [defaults registerDefaults:appDefaults];
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>

#ifndef Q_OS_MAC
void disableMomentumScroll() {}
#else
extern "C" { void disableMomentumScroll(); }
#endif

float rnd(float range) { return (qrand() / static_cast<float>(RAND_MAX)) * range; }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    disableMomentumScroll();
    QGraphicsScene s;
    for (int n = 0; n < 30; n++) {
        s.addRect(rnd(500), rnd(3000), rnd(200), rnd(1000), QPen(Qt::red), QBrush(Qt::gray));
    }
    QGraphicsView w(&s);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```